# How to build debug apk together with signed apk

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm wondering if it's possible to have Gradle set up to build the debug apk whenever I request a signed apk, so that I can keep a copy of the debug version for every version code even if I forget to build it.